# Representation of constant (ideally literal) circular objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have some quite circularly structured Javascript objects which are relatively expensive to compute. I would like to be able to represent them in source code as (almost) literals so that they do not need to be recomputed. There is an example of the sort of library function I am looking for a few paragraphs further down.

There once was some proposed notation for this, [sharp variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/Sharp_variables_in_JavaScript), but they were only ever supported in old versions of Firefox.

Certainly then, objects cannot be represented as literals if they have any circular references so what I would like is to convert a Javascript object into some code for a small function to create it. This can then be manually copied into the source file to be used.

For the sake of example, I will call the function I am looking for `print`. I would want behaviour roughly like this:

```
console.log(print({a:1,b:{c:2,d:3}})); // {a:1,b:{c:2,d:3}} (a string)

var obj = [null,null];
obj[0]=obj[1]=obj; //with sharp variables: obj = #1=[#1#,#1#]
console.log(print(obj));
// e.g. (function(){var u=void 0,a1=[u,u];a1[0]=a1;a1[1]=a1;return a1;})()

var obj = {a:1,
           some:{b:2,
                 nested:{c:3,
                         cyclic:{d:4}}}};
obj.some.nested.cyclic.structure = obj;
//obj = #1={a:1,some:{b:2,nested:{c:3,cyclic:{d:4,structure:#1#}}}}

console.log(print(obj));
//e.g. (function(){var u=void 0,a1={a:1,some:{b:2,nested:{c:3,cyclic:{\
//      d:4,structure:u};a1.some.nested.cyclic.structure=a1;return a1;})()

//OR e.g. (function(){var u=void 0,a1={a:1,some:u},a2={b:2,nested:u},...
//         a1.some=a2;a2.nested=a3;a3.cyclic=a4;a4.structure=a1; return a1;})()
```

Essentially, for any object made only out of JS primatives/plain objects/arrays, we should have that `eval(print(x))` is structurally (i.e. deeply) equal to `x` but not identical. In other words, `eval(print(x))` would be a (stupid) way to make a deep copy of `x` (but respecting cycles)

I would prefer something more like the first option than the second. Presumably some pretty printing could also be achieved but this is optional. Also I don't really care much about small details like using `void 0` instead of undefined.

I know that libraries exist which can serialise circular objects but they do this to some custom notation inside normal tree-structured javascript objects and therefore they require extra code to deserialise. I do not need this and so I'm hoping to avoid it.

I suppose that if you are able to print an object to sharp variables notation, you could reasonably easily convert this to the form like the above as follows:

1. Print with sharp variables (without repeating e.g. `#1=`, etc)
2. Count number of distinct sharp variables used.
3. Make a Javascript variable name for each, e.g. `a1` and maybe a name for the root too.
4. replace all `#n#` with undefined, keeping track of their place in the tree
5. for each `#n#` generate code like: `an['path'][1]['to']['object'] = am`
6. add return statement for root.

It does however seem even less likely for there to exist some library to print objects with sharp variables than to just print the code directly.

Comment: Nice question. But why?? I dont see any need of sharp variables anymore...

Comment: @Jonasw because there are cases when circular objects are useful. In my case they are also constant but relatively expensive to compute. In the most general case, one may want a (cyclic) graph do to computations with.

Answer (score 0):

Well here is an answer anyway:

```
function isPrimitive(x){
  switch(typeof x){
    case "number":
    case "string":
    case "boolean":
    case "undefined":
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function isSerialisable(x){
  switch(typeof x){
    case "function":
    case "symbol":
      return false;
    case "number":
    case "string":
    case "object":
    case "boolean":
    case "undefined":
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function isValidIdentifier(string){
  //this is *really* stupid
  //TODO: operate brain
  if(/[] ,;'".+=-()[]!*/.test(string)) return false; 
  //don't want anything too stupid
  try{ 
    //this throws a syntax error if our identifier is invalid!
    //note that whilst e.g. `var in = ...` is invalid, `foo.in` is valid
    void new Function("x", "return x." + string + ";")
  } catch(e) { return false;}
  return true;
}


function serialise(object){
  var seenObjects = new Map();
  var places = [];

  //this function traverses object in depth-first order,
  //simultaneously finding recursive references and
  //building up a tree-shaped near-deep-copy of object that can be
  //JSON.stringified
  function process(object, path){
    if(!isSerialisable(object)) throw "Object is not serialisable";
    if(isPrimitive(object)) return object;
    //object really is an object now
    if(seenObjects.has(object)){
      places.push({path:path.slice(),from:seenObjects.get(object)});
      return null; //so we don't have cycles.
      //we use null so it is included by JSON.stringify so that the
      //order of the keys is preserved.
    } else {
      //iterate over the own properties
      var ret = Array.isArray(object) ? [] : {} //maybe Object.create(null); doesn't really matter
      seenObjects.set(object, path.slice()); //so we can find it again
      for(var prop in object){
        if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, prop)){
          var p = +prop;
          prop = (p == prop && prop !== "") ? p : prop;
          path.push(prop);
          ret[prop] = process(object[prop], path);
          console.assert(prop == path.pop(), "Path stack not maintained");
        }
      }
      return ret;
    }
  }
  function dotPath(path){
    return path.map(function(x){
      if(isValidIdentifier(x)){
        return "." + x;
      } else {
        return "[" + JSON.stringify(x) + "]";
      }}).join("");
    //we use JSON.stringify to properly escape strings
    //therefore we hope that they do not contain the types of vertical space
    //which JSON ignores.
  }

  var tree = process(object, []);
  if(places.length == 0){
    //object not cyclic
    return JSON.stringify(tree);
  }
  //object is cyclic
  var result = "(function(){x=" + JSON.stringify(tree) + ";"
  return result + places.map(function(obj){
    //obj = {path:..., from:...}
    return "x" + dotPath(obj.path) + "=x" + dotPath(obj.from);
  }).join(";") + ";return x;})()";
}
```

A few of the helper functions are particularly aweful but the main part is mostly OK, if a little memory-heavy for large objects. Perhaps using conses to make a linked list for paths would cut the memory usage a little.

Comment: Note that while this works in theory, it searches depth-first (a pretty-printer using sharp-variables (by which I really mean a lisp pretty-printer) would need to do this) and this can lead to some very deep nesting for objects that are very self-referential but not so deep (e.g certain shallow acyclic digraphs) and thus a large amount of code to refer to those strict members. A breadth-first solution is slightly better but for my use cases, even this can lead to output that is too large. What is needed is I think separating the object heuristically to output something like the last example.

Answer (score 0):

I think implementing sharp variables is complicated and doesnt make computing easier. I would implement a behaviour like this with functions:

```
var sharps={};
Object.prototype.sharp=function(str){
 sharps[str]=this;
}
function gs(str){
return function(){return sharps[str];};
}
```

So you could do:

```
var obj1={a:{b:gs("1");}
obj1.sharp("1");
alert(obj1.a.b());//returns obj1
```

I know this is not what you really wanted. May somebody finds a better solution...

Comment: The point isn't so much to implement sharps -- they are just an example, but to serialise circular objects

Comment: But isnt it better to just create them if they are needed (concerning memory consumption etc)??

Comment: The source code alone to construct the object uses more memory than the object. It would be a constant and so need be created only once.